# Why aren't standard library common mathematical functions "constant expressions"?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, cmath

For some reason, clang++ (but not g++) complains about:

```
constexpr double invdecayf1m(double x) {
  return -log1p(-x);
}
```

telling me that

```
non-constexpr function 'log1p' cannot be used in a constant expression
  return -log1p(-x);
```

Why aren't [common mathematical functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math) declared in `<cmath>` all declared to be [“`constexpr` functions”](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)?

Comment: What if you need a loop to compute ? :)

Comment: @Drax: Are loops allowed?  Recursion definitely is.  (See the `constexpr` link in my question.)

Comment: So somone need to rewrite all the math library in a recursive way (afaik loops are not allowed) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only reason is nobody wrote a proposal to make them constexpr. In general it is possible as they are pure functions. Implementations can use compiler intrinsics to implement them for theier lib, so no "real" implementation is needed. But without proposal you can not count on `constexpr` implementations of these features.

Answer (score 1):

The math library as implied in the name `<cmath>` comes from c and was written when `constexpr` was not even an idea.

In order for most functions to be `constexpr` you would have to rewrite the whole library in a `constexpr` way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the link you posted :

> ```
>  the function body must be either deleted or defaulted or contain only
>  the following:
> ```
>
> ....
>           **exactly one return statement that contains only literal values, constexpr variables and functions.**

The functions there are not that simple. As a matter of fact, they are quite complex, and not possible to implement as a single return statement. Trigonometric, logarithmic and hyperbolic functions are quite complex, and difficult to implement as constexpr functions.

Comment: C++14 will have [relaxed constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions) for constexpr functions, so your answer will be no longer valid.

Comment: I'd rather say "hard" than "not possible", since as long as you have the `?:` operator and recursion you can implement nearly everything that does not require runtime knowledge (memory operations).

Comment: @ForNeVeR Good. Since, the question is about c++11

Comment: @Drax I'd really like to see the implementation of sinh or tan implemented using only `?:` operator :)

Comment: The standard do not enforce the implementation solution and if one day it asks for constexpr mathematical function, as we still are in a compiler stage, a compiler may replace them with intrinsics. just like it is impossible to write some type_traits with pure C++. And as constexpr may give a hard time to compilation times, that is a good reason to hard wire that kind of functions.

Comment: @BЈовић `constexpr float sinh(float x) {return 0.5 * (exp(x)-exp(-x));}` Now you just need a `constexpr` exp :D

Comment: @galop1n For example `RSQRTPS` (inverse square root)? The results are far from good, although it is quite fast. What about platforms that do not support intrinsic functions?

Comment: To write `exp` using `constexpr`, you replace variables with parameters, conditions with ternary operators, and loops with recursion.  Nice to see that C++14 will relax these restrictions.

Comment: @BЈовић I do not see them as entry points to the real CPU instructions but as the constexpr are evaluated during the compilation, it is possible to hard wire functions instead of a generic implementation that need to respect the constexpr rules. And rsqrtps is fine with two newton-raphson passes.

Comment: This is wrong, nothing in the standard requires functions within `std` to be actual functions

Comment: recursion and looping are equivalent, so as far as I am concerned, the C++11 restrictions on `constexpr` are just an implementaion artifact