# Can I compute values that require a special function during compilation of C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I appreciate I am being somewhat vague about what is exactly my issue, but I think that the fundamental question is clear. Please bear with me for a moment.

In brief, I have a `static constexpr` array of points which are used to find certain bounds I need to use. These bounds depend only on the array, so they can be precomputed. However, we want to be able to change these points and it is a pain to go and change every value every time we try to test something.

For example, let's say that I have the following setup:

The `static constexpr` array is

```
static constexpr double CHECK_POINTS[7] = { -1.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 1.0, 1.5 };
```

and then in a function I'm calling, I have the following block of code:

```
std::vector<double> bounds = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
for(int i=0; i<bounds.size(); i++)
{
    bounds[i] = std::exp(CHECK_POINTS[i]);
}
```

Clearly, the values of `bounds` can be computed during compilation. Is there anyway I can make gcc do that?

EDIT: The vector in my code block is not essential, an array will do.

Comment: write a constexpr function.

Comment: @appleapple just that? It doesn't need any special treatment?

Comment: @tst It does. You need to make the function `constexpr`.

Comment: There are some rules in `constexpr` functions, not every syntax is legal. But in C++17, you can have advanced power including loops. If the compiler accepts to compile, it should work.

Comment: The rules are explained here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression

Comment: @appleapple [`std::exp` isn't required to be `constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp). In fact [most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42189190/995714) [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17347935/995714) in [`cmath`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21303498/995714) [aren't `constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50477974/995714) and the proposal to make them `constexpr` hasn't been approved yet although some implementations do make them constexpr themselves

Comment: @phuclv I believe that's not problem. I'm more concerned constexpr construct of vector.

Comment: @JasonLiam it isn't simple like that. You can't call a non constexpr function like `std::exp` in a constexpr function

Comment: @appleapple I wouldn't care about that first. It's easy to construct a fixed list of bounds but only after you have a constexpr way to calculate the values

Comment: @phuclv it's fine with array https://godbolt.org/z/be57xsGjf

Comment: @appleapple as I said, that's a [gcc extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70523217/995714). It [wont' work in other compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/j4jY9saG4). And FYI [there's `constexpr std::vector` in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801072/995714) so that won't be a problem. The only issue here is the constexpr std::exp

Comment: @phuclv yes, but the `constexpr std::vector` doesn't seems to works here anyway https://godbolt.org/z/E8fY33nYs

Comment: @phuclv til it's gcc extension, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`constexpt std::vector` does not work here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working), but you can use `std::array`.
- [`std::exp` is not constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347935/constexpr-math-functions)
  so you need to find `constexpr` alternatives

  - it would work in gcc as an extension.

```cpp
static constexpr double CHECK_POINTS[7] = { -1.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 1.0, 1.5 };

static constexpr auto vec = [](){
    std::array bounds = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    for(int i=0; i<bounds.size(); i++)
    {
        bounds[i] = std::exp(CHECK_POINTS[i]);
    }
    return bounds;
}();
```

it's would compile fine with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/x5a9q9M1d

---

(`constexpr std::exp` is an gcc extension, thanks to @phuclv to point out)